# How to avoid foundation vertical tab url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs, zurb-foundation

I am using [foundation 5 vertical tabs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html). It is working fine, but clicking on tabs adding id's to the URL.

```
<dl class="tabs vertical" data-tab>
  <dd class="active"><a href="#panel1">Tab 1</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#panel2">Tab 2</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#panel3">Tab 3</a></dd>
</dl>

<div class="tabs-content">
  <div class="content active" id="panel1">
    <p>tab1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel2">
    <p>tab2.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel3">
    <p>tab3.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

`http://localhost:3000/#panel1`

`http://localhost:3000/#panel2`

`http://localhost:3000/#panel3`

I don't want the href to show up in the URL. Is there any option I could pass to avoid the URL?

Edit: In [foundation tab page](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html) they are showing a bunch of examples for tabs and in their examples the anchors are not getting added to the URL so there must be an option to avoid it which is not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: I just tried it with Foundation 5.4.5 and everything seems to work fine for me (no ids getting added to the URL). Are you sure you are initializing the Foundation JS in your project? What specific version of Foundation 5 are you running?

Comment: I am using foundation 5.4.5 in meteor.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not... you are using anchors for id as a symbol for the place where it should aim.

Comment: yes but in few libraries like [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#initialization) they are giving options to hide the anchors. It is also using the same concept without shows anchors in the url

Answer (score 0):

On the same page that you linked there is a piece of info about deep linking

> To enable deep linking set `data-options="deep_linking:true"`. If the
>   location hash maps to an element ID within a tab content pane, then
>   the appropriate tab will become active and the browser window will
>   scroll to the specified element. If you do not want to scroll to the
>   specified element then set `data-options="scroll_to_content: false"`.

I would try setting `scroll_to_content` and `deep_linking` to false if that is what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul.tabs li a").bind('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Above code will resolve your issue